# Composer: Package that extends another from a fork

Tags: git, dependencies, fork, composer-php

I've the following situation: There is package `author/package1` on GitHub and Packagist. I decided to fork it into `tcb13/package1` to add some code (that will eventually get merged into the original project, however it will take time).

Later on, I developed another package, `tcb13/package1-extension` that extends the fork `tcb13/package1` by inhering some of it's methods into new classes...

At my `tcb13/package1-extension`, `composer.json` I wrote:

```
{
    "name": "tcb13/package1-extension",
    "description": "...",
    "keywords": [

    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/tcb13/package1-extension",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [

    ],
    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/tcb13/package1/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "author/package1": "dev-master"
    },
```

I told composer that my extension package needs `author/package1` and also there was an aditional repository `https://github.com/tcb13/package1/` and set the package version to `dev-master` so composer would download `author/package1` from my modified fork, instead of the original package... (it wouldn't work if I told it to download from `tcb13/package1`).

I submitted the code above to GitHub and tried to require `tcb13/package1-extension` on a new project, and composer said this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for tcb13/package1-extension dev-master -> satisfiable by tcb13/package1-extension[dev-master].
    -  tcb13/package1-extension dev-master requires `author/package1` dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

Why the error? When I was developing my extension package I was able to require `author/package1` as `dev-master` because it was pointed to my fork repo, however when I try require `tcb13/package1-extension` it seems like it doesn't look for my fork and tries to go to the original project looking for the branch... Why?

Also, is this the way I should use forks as dependencies? Is there other way? I originally tried to require the fork as `tcb13/package1` but it would fail, however requiring it as `author/package1` also telling composer I had a extra repository worked until now.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the name of the tcb13/package1 inside composer.json?

Comment: Actually at `tcb13/package1` composer.json I didn't touch the name variable, am I supposed to?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. For a simple fix that is excepted to be accepted as a pull request in the original package, you can survive the time until a new release.

Comment: So, why doesn't it work? Why am I able to require the fork at `tcb13/package1-extension` but when I try to require `tcb13/package1-extension`  at another project it isn't able to get the fork? It should always fail or never fail... not work in one and fail at another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to this fix. According to composer docs, this is not an error, it's something that happens by design due to security.

From a GitHub [comment](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3780#issuecomment-76214657):

> Consider this: you have a project that depends on one of my packages.
>   I depend on a package that is critical to your application. I happen
>   to make a fork to introduce a new feature and accidentally tag a
>   release with the repository in my composer.json. You happen to update
>   your package and get my fork that is potentially broken and definitely
>   not what you were expecting when you defined your package dependency.

In order to be able to do what I want, I had to manually add to my final project `tcb13/final-project` the URL of the fork of `author/package1` (the same way I did on `tcb13/package1-extension`), like:

```
{
    "repositories":
    [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/tcb13/package1/" // Fork of author/package1
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/tcb13/package1-extension"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "author/package1": "dev-master", // Reference to the original package, composer will fetch this from my fork defined above...
        "tcb13/package1-extension": "dev-master" // My current extension package
    }
}
```

After `composer update` it all worked as expected.